# Slim Framework - Multiple PDO updates from json

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, slim

Im trying to do multiple inserts in a json put request using the Slim framework and I get a strange error of:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Chester'
```

Even though the Name is a VARCHAR. It errors on the $sth->execute line. If I only use one entry it sometimes works. Here is the JSON

```
[{"id":"2240","name":"Cheats","breed": "Maltys"},
{"id":"2241","name":"Chester","breed":"Poodlexx"}]
```

Code:

```
$app->put('/test2', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();
    print_r ($parsedBody);
    foreach ($parsedBody as $key => &$value) {
        if (!isset($value['id'])) { continue; }
        $sql = "UPDATE pets p SET";
        foreach ($value as $p_key => &$p_value) {
            if ($p_key !== 'id') { //ignore the id
                $sql .= " $p_key = :$p_key AND";
            }
        }
        $sql = preg_replace('/AND$/', '', $sql)." WHERE p.id = :id";
        //echo "\n$sql";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($value as $p_key => &$p_value) {
            //echo "\n$p_key:$p_value";
            $sth->bindParam($p_key, $p_value);
        }
        $sth->debugDumpParams();
        $sth->execute();
    }
    return;
});
```

Output of DumpParams:

```
SQL: [67] UPDATE pets p SET name = :name AND breed = :breed  WHERE p.id = :id
```

Comment: This error message comes from the database engine (MySQL?), not PHP, let alone Slim. You should inspect the value of the `$sql` variable. In any case, your overall approach looks kind of scary from the security standpoint...

Comment: Security wise, you can set anything you like for any ID.. other than that is there any other thing I should be aware of?

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, anything you submit as JSON key becomes a SQL literal expression. You can possibly send a carefully crafted request to write into any arbitrary table.

Comment: I would love to try to break it.. do you have any data examples to try?

Comment: I'm far from being a security specialist but the usual approach is to leverage SQL comment syntax and I guess subqueries could be abused somehow. Sorry for not being more specific but, as I said, not really my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, after 2 hours of banging my head it was an incorrect SQL statement should have been a comma not an AND:

```
 foreach ($value as $p_key => &$p_value) {
            if ($p_key !== 'id') { //ignore the id
                $sql .= " $p_key = :$p_key,";
            }
        }
        $sql = preg_replace('/,$/', '', $sql)." WHERE p.id = :id";
```

Comment: the need to have the preg_replace to build the SQL string in the first place looks like the higher cause of flaw to me. A lightweight alternative here would be to pair in an array and implode() afterwards. That would be more strict about what it does (e.g. if no element matches). Technically preg_replace() does work here, so just saying.